Problem installing PyTorch 1.9.0 on Windows 10 x64 with Python 3.8 using pip
I'm trying to install PyTorch 1.9.0 on my Windows 10 64-bit system with Python 3.8, but pip can't find the proper distribution. When I try to install it using the command:
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio

I get the following error:
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

To solve the problem, I tried to download the corresponding .whl file from the page https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/ and chose torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl. However, when I try to install it with the command:
pip install torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl

I get the following error:
ERROR: torch-1.9.0+cpu-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Additional details:

Operating System: Windows 10 x64
Python version: 3.8


pip install torch==1.9.0 torchvision==0.10.0 torchaudio==0.9.0

if not installed or get error again can download pytorch wheel alone.
make your directory of install = path of downloaded wheel , then
pip install <name of wheel>

https://pypi.org/project/torch/#files

or
pip install pytorch_wheel_installer

pip install git+https://github.com/pmeier/pytorch_wheel_installer


Thank you very much for your reply. Unfortunately I still have the same error. ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfying the requirement torch==1.9.0 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch==1.9.0

first pip install --upgrade pip
then pip install torch==1.9.0+cpu torchvision==0.10.0+cpu torchaudio==0.9.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
it's may be cuda error!
